# How to display blog post detail page in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

How can I display the blog post page when a specific slug appears in URL like ".blog/post-slug". I am trying to save post article HTML code in an array in PostData.jsx file. How to fetch data from it and display it to the user.

PostData.jsx File

```
const PostData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        slug: "post-slug",
        content: `Here HTML Content`,
    }
]
```

Post.jsx File

```
const Post = () => {
    }

export default Post;
```

Or is there any other optimized method to display it?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a more [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what you are trying to do. Currently there's just not enough context to help diagnose and debug the code we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-router` to achieve that:

```
<Route path="/blog/:slug">
  <Post />
</Route>
```

You can use `useParams` hook on the post page to get slug:

```
const Post = () => {
  const { slug } = useParams();
  const currentPost = postData.find((post) => post.slug === slug);

  return (
    // render
  );
}
```

More info about `react-router` and `useParams` hook: 
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams

Comment: Can you please elaborate more because I am getting a white blank screen.